# know Physical Address for my windows PC

Tags: networking

I have type ipconfig/all in cmd and it is showing two physical address(mac address) for wireless network connection.
One in "wireless Network connection2" and other in "wireless Network connection"

I want to know which one is the correct wireless Physical(MAC) address for my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have 2 wireless cards installed, that's why your computer has two MAC addresses. Or you could have a virtual network device which too have MAC addresses. Either way if you have 2 MAC, then you should check in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections which one you are using to connect to your network and that MAC would be for your computer on your network.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's unclear what your exact problem is, I can only assume you have to troubleshoot which adapter is in use.  You can determine which wireless MAC address is in use at a given time by using the following PowerShell command:

`Get-NetAdapter –Physical`

This show output like this:

Name    Interface   Description  ifIndex  Status     MacAddress        LinkSpeed

`adap1  Marvell Avastar        12       Up        00-24-9B-09-47-83    0 bps`
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                          
`adap2  Broadcom NetXtreme     4        Up        A8-20-66-19-3D-23    1 Gbps`